# Getting output from adb command in python pygui to populate combo

Tags: python, adb, dearpygui

im using python and pygui to make a simple window that has a combo box that will list the files in a directory of an ADB device. For example if the folder has pictures, i would like to list all the pictures in phone directory and have them populate the combo box.

what i have

`out2 = subprocess.getstatusoutput('adb shell ls SOMEDIRECTORY')`
 `combo_id = dpg.add_combo(out2)`

this works (no errors) but it gives me 1 selection that i can choose (0) and all the files are in one big section and cannot be selected individually in the combo box.

if i do

`print(out[1])`

this shows me what i want but when i input that into the combo it gives and error

`combo_id = dpg.add_combo(out2[1])`

the error is

*Exception: Error: [1008] Message:     Python value error. Must be List[str].*

*combo_id = dpg.add_combo(out2[1])*
File "/Users/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/dearpygui/dearpygui.py", line 3544, in add_combo
return internal_dpg.add_combo(items, label=label, user_data=user_data, *use_internal_label=use_internal_label, tag=tag, width=width, indent=indent, parent=parent, before=before, source=source, payload_type=payload_type, callback=callback, drag_callback=drag_callback, drop_callback=drop_callback, show=show, enabled=enabled, pos=pos, filter_key=filter_key, tracked=tracked, track_offset=track_offset, default_value=default_value, popup_align_left=popup_align_left, no_arrow_button=no_arrow_button, no_preview=no_preview, height_mode=height_mode, **kwargs)
SystemError:  returned a result with an error set

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the format you are expecting but you may need something like this to split the lines

```py
p = subprocess.run(['adb', 'ls', SOMEDIRECTORY], capture_output=True)
out2 = [l.split()[3].decode('UTF-8') for l in p.stdout.splitlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

So i was able to do something similar to this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58630684/19080534

my problem was that i needed to do a list[str], its similar to the answer posted above.

thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).